# iOS External Accessory Framework accessoryDidConnect not firing

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I have an iOS app that connects to a device using External Accessory Framework.  When I first start the app the accessoryDidConnect event won't fire.  I have to disconnect and reconnect the USB cable connected to the device in order for the event to fire.  Any idea why this is happening?  I can't debug since the phone has to be connected to the device via a USB cable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the registerForLocalNotifications method? Your controllers won't observe the notification values without calling this method to indicate that you're actively wanting to observe the notifications.

Swift

```
EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().registerForLocalNotifications()
```

Objective-C

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
```